# My CPU wont start until I un-plug and re-plug the power cable several times

Tags: cpu, boot

My CPU wont start until I un-plug and re-plug the power cable several times either from the mains or from the back of the CPU. I have changed the power cable but no go....What might be wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a failed power supply or a loose connection inside the computer case.

If you feel comfortable opening the case, try unplugging and repluging the cables from the power supply to the respective devices (motherboard, hard drive, graphics card, etc).

If that doesn't work, and you have a different power supply to test, you could always swap that out and test.

Comment: Thanks Kruug I will try that. Also some time the keyboard doesn't get recognized...Any clues??

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bad motherboard.